# JSonString deserialze To NSArray with jsonkit

Tags: ios, nsarray, json, jsonkit

how do I  deserialize this **JSON** string to `NSSArray` using jsonkit.

```
[{"answer": "AAA", "questionId": "1"}, {"answer": "BBB", "questionId": "2"}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
 NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
 NSArray *jsonValues = [jsonDictionary allValues];
```